# Cómo saber que ha introducido el usuario tras la pregunta para después mostrar una cosa u otra

Tags: c++, condiciones

Quiero crear un programa que dibuje un rectángulo o un cuadrado según lo que responda el usuario a la pregunta inicial. Si escribe `c`, entonces dibujar el cuadrado en una pestaña gracias a la librería gfx. Si responde `r`, dibujar el rectángulo.

Mi problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que detecte si ha introducido esa "`c`" o "`r`" para después seguir con lo que busco.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "gfx.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    char c;
    char r;
    cout << "¿Quieres dibujar un cuadrado o un rectángulo?(C/R): ";
    cin >> "C o R";
    if (c){
        cout << "Has pedido un cuadrado." << endl;
    } else if(r){ 
        cout << "Has pedido un rectángulo.";
    } else{
        cout << "No has introducido ni C ni R :(";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buscá cómo leer lo ingresado con `cin`...

Comment: Que es lo que esperas que haga esta linea `cin >> "C o R";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para leer de la consola, debes usar `std::cin` pero hacia una variable:

```
char respuesta;
std::cin >> respuesta;
//          ^^^^^^^^^ <-- aquí guardas lo que escribe el usuario.

switch (respuesta)
{
case 'c': /* cuadrado */   break;
case 'r': /* rectángulo */ break;
default:
    std::cout << "Opción no válida\n";
}
```